# Svelte on:click function updates data, but not UI

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am new to Svelte, so I suspect this is a very fundamental lack-of-understanding issue.

Can someone explain why the on:click updates the UI, but the UI will not update if I attempt to use the changeJob(items)? The console.log indicates all jobs were changed in the array, but the UI does not reflect that.

```
<script>
  import ListItem from './ListItem.svelte';

  let items = [
    { name: 'John', age: 23, job: 'plumber'},
    { name: 'Jane', age: 45, job: 'hair stylist'},
    { name: 'Juan', age: 18, job: 'student'},
  ];

  const changeJob = (arr) => {
    console.log(arr[0].job);
    arr[0].job = 'clown';
    console.log(arr[0].job);
  }

</script>

<button on:click={() => items[0].job = 'clown'}>Clownify</button>

<ul>
  {#each items as item }
    <ListItem {...item}/>
  {/each}
</ul>
```

Code snippet: [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/99cb1dede6004b42b741bc273e2408a8?version=3.24.0)

Answer (score 4):

When you have some code like this...

```js
items[0].job = 'clown'
```

...Svelte understands that it needs to update anything that depends on `items`, because the assignment is to a property of something it recognises as a top-level variable inside `<script>`.

But when you do this...

```js
const changeJob = (arr) => {
  arr[0].job = 'clown';
}
```

...you're *not* assigning to a property of a top-level variable, you're assigning to a property of the local `arr` variable inside the function. It's effectively opaque to Svelte.

It will work if you just get rid of the local variable, like so:

```js
const changeJob = () => {
  items[0].job = 'clown';
}
```